# Email Form Solution After selecting Email Recipient

Tags: email, form-submit

I am rather new to the field and ran into a frustrating situation. I have a website that I am working on that is a collection of group members. The site is a basic info site with contact information and links to the members' individual sites. One of the options is to email the member directly (all members have different email providers).

I found numerous options to incorporate an email form (rather than current mailto: option used) and to send the form to one recipient via server-side script. I was not able to find a solution that would allow me to change the email address depending on the member chosen without creating multiple forms or increasing the html file size.

Is there a technology or resource I should explore to help me solve this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thanks